# Trouble with Promises completing

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

The user will click a button which will call:

```
private _saveJobCreate(): void {
  if ((this.state.jobToCreate.TruckLookUpId && this.state.jobToCreate.TruckLookUpId !== undefined) &&
    (this.state.jobToCreate.DeliveryDate && this.state.jobToCreate.DeliveryDate.length > 0)) {
    console.log("valid input, should save");

    this._createJob(this.state.jobToCreate)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("job created and should be fetched, hiding panel");
        this._hideJobCreatePanel();
      });
  }
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
private _createJob(newJob: IDeliveryJob): Promise < void > {
  console.log("creating job");
  let promise: Promise < void > = new Promise < void > ((resolve, reject) => {
    this.props.deliveryJobService.createJob(newJob)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("job created, fetching jobs");
        this._fetchJobs()
          .then(() => {

          });
      });
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Which will fetch my jobs from a Sharepoint list:

```
private _fetchJobs(): Promise < void > {
  console.log("fetching jobs");
  let promise: Promise < void > = new Promise < void > ((resolve, reject) => {
    this.props.deliveryJobService.getDeliveryJobs()
      .then((newJobs: IDeliveryJob[]) => {
        console.log("jobs fetched, setting state");
        this.setState({
          jobs: newJobs
        });
      });
  });
  return promise;
}
```

The issue is it stops at setting the state, the last console.log I see is:

> fetching jobs DeliveryJobService.ts:59 response.json:  ƒ (){return
>   this.nativeResponse.json()} DeliveryJobService.ts:63 response.value: 
>   (24) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
>   {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>   TruckDeliverySchedule.tsx:503 jobs fetched, setting state

So, it looks like the last method `_fetchJobs()` is not returning its `Promise` so the first method can call `_hideJobCreatePanel()`.

I'm pretty new with typescript/javascript development and I can't figure out why the last `Promise` isn't being return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never `resolve` or `reject` -ing any of you're promises, and what's more you've fallen into the [anti-pattern](https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/) of a wrapping perfectly good promises in your own Promise.

For example, instead of this:

```
private _fetchJobs(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("fetching jobs");
    let promise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.deliveryJobService.getDeliveryJobs()
      .then((newJobs: IDeliveryJob[]) => {
        console.log("jobs fetched, setting state");
        this.setState ({
          jobs: newJobs
        });
      });  
    });

    return promise;
}
```

you should do this:

```
private _fetchJobs(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("fetching jobs");
    return this.props.deliveryJobService.getDeliveryJobs()
      .then((newJobs: IDeliveryJob[]) => {
        console.log("jobs fetched, setting state");
        this.setState ({
          jobs: newJobs
        });
      });  
}
```

When you do this in `_createJob` don't forget to *return* the chained promise:

```
 private _createJob(newJob: IDeliveryJob): Promise<void> {
    console.log("creating job");
    return this.props.deliveryJobService.createJob(newJob)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("job created, fetching jobs");
        return this._fetchJobs() // HERE!
          .then(() => {

          });
      });  
  }
```

Each of your methods should return the promise, not wrap it in a new one, and then your problem will no longer exist... and what's more you can just chain your calls, which makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you’re using the Promise constructor where you don’t need to.

```
private _fetchJobs(): Promise<void> {
      console.log("fetching jobs");
      return this.props.deliveryJobService.getDeliveryJobs().then((newJobs: IDeliveryJob[]) => {
         console.log("jobs fetched, setting state");
         this.setState ({
           jobs: newJobs
         });
       });

  }
```